# Is it possible to return frozen, deduplicated strings from String#split function in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, memory

If we have a string like this "1,2,3,4,5" and we parse it using a split function to get individual elements, Ruby allocates a new string object for each element. If you process a big file, which has a lot of duplicated values, for example a lot of 0s, then returning frozen strings will save a lot of time and memory since interpreter wouldn't have to create these new objects - it could return a reference to the frozen string - and it wouldn't need to clean up after them.

So instead of this: (every string object is unique)

```
2.4.1 :007 > "1,2,3,4,5,6".split(',').map(&:object_id)
 => [70280975267840, 70280975267820, 70280975267800, 70280975267780, 70280975267760, 70280975267740]
2.4.1 :008 > "1,2,3,4,5,6".split(',').map(&:object_id)
 => [70280978671420, 70280978671400, 70280978671380, 70280978671360, 70280978671340, 70280978671320]
```

I would like to see this: ( we get the same string objects in the first and in the second run )

```
2.4.1 :007 > "1,2,3,4,5,6".split(',').map(&:object_id)
 => [70280975267840, 70280975267820, 70280975267800, 70280975267780, 70280975267760, 70280975267740]
2.4.1 :008 > "1,2,3,4,5,6".split(',').map(&:object_id)
 => [70280975267840, 70280975267820, 70280975267800, 70280975267780, 70280975267760, 70280975267740]
```

Of course, this would need to be some kind of opt-in mechanism, which for example allows you to specify the list of frozen strings you would like to use since freezing each word in a file sounds like asking for trouble.

So ideally the interface would be like this:

```
"1,2,3,4,5,6".split(',', frozen_strings: [-'1', -'2', -'3', -'4', -'5', -'6'])
```

Is there any way to do this in Ruby without writing a C extension? Maybe using some external libraries like CSV parsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short Answer: No

If your goal is to use frozen strings to "save a lot of time and memory", then no, that can't be done with `split`, because Ruby isn't really designed for memory management concerns like that.

Basically:

```rb
long_string.split(',') # already too late, memory allocations have happened
```

### But Possible

Your only recourse in pure Ruby is to not create the strings in the first place by implementing a streaming split yourself. Note that you'll have to avoid all the normal string iteration/access methods like `each_char` and even `[]`:

```rb
str = "1,2,3,4,5"

# both will keep allocating new String objects
str.each_char.map(&:object_id)
(0...str.size).map { |i| str[i].object_id }
```

You'll have to use something like `each_codepoint` instead:

```rb
str.each_codepoint { |code| code } # does not keep allocating new objects

# so you could:
str.each_codepoint do |code|
  # implement your own parser, taking care to avoid dynamic memory allocations
end
```

In fact, if you are truly working with *big* files, you wouldn't even want to have the entire string loaded in memory at all. You'll want to stream file reads with something like [`IO.read`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/IO.html#method-c-read)

And just to get full closure, supposing you've implemented this, you can then monkeypatch that feature into `String` within your application to get what you wanted in the first place.

### Proof

```rb
str = "1,2,3,4,5"
puts "Run in another shell:"
puts "watch -n 1 'ps ax -o pid,rss | grep -E \"^[[:space:]]*#{$$}\"'"
GC.disable

loop do
  # doesn't keep allocating memory
  str.each_codepoint { |code| code }

  # these keep allocating memory
  # str.each_char { |c| c }
  # (0...str.size).each { |i| str[i] }
end
```

**Addendum**

Extending from [OP's PoC posted in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63677308/234593):

```rb
NUMS = [1, 2, 3]
LONG_STR = Array.new(99_999_999) { NUMS.sample.to_s }.join(','); nil

Benchmark.bm(20) do |m|
  m.report('my_split') { my_split(LONG_STR) }

  m.report('split') { LONG_STR.split(',') }

  results = [0, nil, nil, nil, nil, 0, 0, 0]
  m.report('tally w/o alloc') do
    LONG_STR.each_codepoint do |codepoint|
      results[codepoint - 44] += 1
    end
  end
end

# Run 1              user     system      total        real
# my_split        28.670430   0.541530  29.211960 ( 30.591287)
# split           11.633294   2.578581  14.211875 ( 14.561345)
# tally w/o alloc 12.797672   0.043086  12.840758 ( 12.963547)

# Run 2              user     system      total        real
# my_split        26.526297   0.897670  27.423967 ( 28.084112)
# split           23.000878   3.849396  26.850274 ( 28.269502)
# tally w/o alloc 12.919090   0.035687  12.954777 ( 13.196385)
```

Just FYI: benchmarking things where a lot of memory "thrashes" is always going to be pretty non-deterministic, as you've no control of when the garbage collector decides to kick in (and slows down execution).

Oh, and `split` might be even faster with `#frozen_string_literal: true`, and I've no idea what'd happen with `--jit`...

Comment: Thanks Kache, your answer is on point! That said, it looks like all the gains from not allocating objects are lost by slowness of this approach. I posted my PoC below and benchmarks below.

Answer (score 3):

You can get a frozen, deduplicated string via [`String#-@`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#2D-40-method).

Either my using `map`:

```
str = '1,1,2,2'

str.split(',').map(&:-@).map(&:object_id)
#=> [70293234167580,
#    70293234167580,
#    70293368908400,
#    70293368908400]
```

or, using the block form to save memory while processing a huge string: (Ruby 2.6+)

```
def frozen_split(str, pattern)
  return enum_for(__method__, str, pattern) unless block_given?

  str.split(pattern) { |x| yield -x }
end
```

and call it via:

```
frozen_split(str, ',').map(&:object_id)
#=> [70293234167580,
#    70293234167580,
#    70293368908400,
#    70293368908400]
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan. Unfortunately this doesn't really solve the problem since you're freezing/deduplicating strings after they've already been created and allocated, so the savings I'm looking for will not occur.

Comment: @rafal that’s correct, but the original strings can be garbage collected right away.

Comment: You're right Stefan. That said, this doesn't improve performance in my case. I had similar results as Timur below - my code was actually a little bit slower with this change.

Answer (score 1):

A simple [`to_sym`](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/to_sym) also allows to reuse the same objects. For example:

```
puts "1,2,3,4,5,6".split(',').map(&:to_sym).map(&:object_id).inspect
puts "1,2,3,4,5,6".split(',').map(&:to_sym).map(&:object_id).inspect
```

This prints the same object ids:

```
[70236707757520, 70236707757480, 70236707757440, 70236707757400, 70236707757360, 70236707757320]
[70236707757520, 70236707757480, 70236707757440, 70236707757400, 70236707757360, 70236707757320]
```

Note that the `to_sym` method, as well as in the answer by Stefan, *should* save memory (I did not measure this), but the conversion itself does take some time.

**So both methods that reuse object ids run slower than the default without conversion**, see benchmarking results below (using `ruby 2.6.6p146 (2020-03-31 revision 67876) [x86_64-darwin18]` ). Note that any code the uses these objects downstream *could* potentially run faster, but I was not sure what that code would be in your case.

**Benchmarking code:**

```
require 'benchmark' 

max_val = 10

[100, 1000, 10_000].each do |num_strings|
  puts "###############################"
  puts "num_strings=#{num_strings}:"
  puts "###############################"
  Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
    Kernel.srand(1234)
    x.report("default") { 10000.times { num_strings.times.map { rand(max_val) }.map(&:to_s).map(&:object_id) } }
    x.report("to_sym")  { 10000.times { num_strings.times.map { rand(max_val) }.map(&:to_s).map(&:to_sym).map(&:object_id) } }
    x.report("-@")      { 10000.times { num_strings.times.map { rand(max_val) }.map(&:to_s).map(&:-@).map(&:object_id) } }
  end
end
```

**Benchmarking results:**

```
###############################
num_strings=100:
###############################
Rehearsal -------------------------------------------
default   0.367201   0.000213   0.367414 (  0.367492)
to_sym    0.477524   0.000333   0.477857 (  0.478012)
-@        0.489703   0.000129   0.489832 (  0.489900)
---------------------------------- total: 1.335103sec

              user     system      total        real
default   0.369533   0.000336   0.369869 (  0.370126)
to_sym    0.504686   0.000775   0.505461 (  0.508025)
-@        0.497052   0.001251   0.498303 (  0.499578)
###############################
num_strings=1000:
###############################
Rehearsal -------------------------------------------
default   3.692454   0.005807   3.698261 (  3.706056)
to_sym    4.628710   0.003317   4.632027 (  4.633834)
-@        4.844655   0.004841   4.849496 (  4.865654)
--------------------------------- total: 13.179784sec

              user     system      total        real
default   3.583169   0.002604   3.585773 (  3.587418)
to_sym    4.709409   0.004160   4.713569 (  4.717487)
-@        4.909228   0.010225   4.919453 (  4.935606)
###############################
num_strings=10000:
###############################
Rehearsal -------------------------------------------
default  37.620197   0.117046  37.737243 ( 37.867851)
to_sym   48.576790   0.156409  48.733199 ( 48.948987)
-@       49.765026   0.105483  49.870509 ( 49.998702)
-------------------------------- total: 136.340951sec

              user     system      total        real
default  36.519696   0.068643  36.588339 ( 36.654737)
to_sym   47.571235   0.157084  47.728319 ( 47.937162)
-@       49.100705   0.177943  49.278648 ( 49.434869)
```

---

**NOTE:**

All these operations are pretty fast. It may be that the bottleneck in your case in not string allocations, etc, but the I/O: reading/writing large files. So you may need to optimize something entirely different, such as avoiding writing large files using pipes, etc.

Comment: Thanks @Timur! I had similar results as you. The problem with your solution is exactly the one described by Kache - it's already to late to save time by avoiding allocation. 

I did quite extensive profiling of my code both performance and memory-wise. After doing all the easy optimizations, StackProf shows that around 50% of time is taken by garbage collection while RubyProf memory profiling shows that 50% of allocated objects is done by `#split` function. And this was the reason why I asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Kache answer I drafted a PoC which solves my problem. That said, this code is much slower than the original `split` function.

```
COMMA_CODE_POINT = ','.ord
ONE_CODE_POINT = '1'.ord
TWO_CODE_POINT = '2'.ord
THREE_CODE_POINT = '3'.ord

def my_split(string)
  result = []
  current_string = []
  string.each_codepoint do |codepoint|
    if codepoint == COMMA_CODE_POINT
      process_string_part(current_string, result)
    else
      current_string << codepoint
    end
  end

  process_string_part(current_string, result)

  result
end

def process_string_part(current_string, result)
  if current_string.size == 1
    case current_string[0]
    when ONE_CODE_POINT
      result << -'1'
    when TWO_CODE_POINT
      result << -'2'
    when THREE_CODE_POINT
      result << -'3'
    else
      result << current_string.pack('U*')
    end
    current_string.clear
  elsif current_string.size > 0
    result << current_string.pack('U*')
    current_string.clear
  end
end
```

Here is a benchmark of this code:

```
a = "1,2,3,3,2,1,1,2,3,3,2,1,\\N,\\N,asdasda asdasd asdad"
n = 10_000_000

Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
  x.report("split") do
    n.times do
      a.split(',')
    end
  end
  x.report("my_split") do
    n.times do
      my_split(a)
    end
  end
end
            user     system      total        real
split    21.926568   0.000002  21.926570 ( 21.927100)
my_split 71.138833   0.000000  71.138833 ( 71.140378)
```

I was able to cut this time and get very close to the original implementation but with very limited functionality - the original string could only contain instances of the expected frozen strings and nothing else and frozen strings had to have one char only. I guess that in some cases this might be enough.

Comment: Thanks! Though I don't think `my_split` avoids all dynamic memory allocations. I've added to my answer an extension of your PoC -- an example of sorts where I was able to "beat" `split`.

Comment: Interesting idea with keeping a tally of all strings! It seems that this approach has quite limited application to places where the order/sequence of split strings is not important - it doesn't look like a drop in replacement for the split function.